# Problem loading dump into IDA Pro

Tags: ida, disassembly

I am attempting to load a PPC memory dump into IDA Pro, but I am getting a "ROM size overflow" error.  The dump is the exact size of the memory location, but IDA Pro will not load without cutting off bytes.

What seems to be the issue?

[image: Disassembly memory organization & error dialogs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in IDA (and probably worth reporting to support@hex-rays.com). Try a ROM size of `0x3FFFFF` as a workaround.